# Single query vs multiple query

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, spring-data

I've a doubt. I've a list of different object and, in some case (when **needToCheckActionCategory** is true, I've to query the database to verify the kind of the object. This is the code:

```
for ( Entry<String, MyObject> tosEntry : "listOfObject".entrySet() ) {

    if ( tosEntry.getValue().getObjectType() == DHCConstants.ACTION ) {

        if ( needToCheckActionCategory > 0 ) {

            Integer entryCategory = pipelineDao.getObjectCategory(tosEntry.getKey());                   
            if ( entryCategory != actionCategory ) {
                continue;
            }

        }

        [...]

    }
}
```

Now I query the **needToCheckActionCategory** is true and if the object is an Action.

My question is: is it better to query the DB only one time asking for the category of all the objects (in this case I need to create the query and go thought the "listOfObject" to get all the IDs) or query the DB if and only if needed but for the single object? So, to recap one single big query that return a big object or more than one call but that returns one small object?

It's a web application, I want to optimize this part.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note here: You should only optimize the code if you have identified it as a performance bottleneck in your application (see also "Item 55: Optimize judiciously" in [Effective Java by Josh Bloch](https://books.google.fi/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=optimize+judiciously&source=bl&ots=yZGmKmv5U3&sig=er8pifRg6iTGKRQrX7lu2_Sbk1M&hl=fi&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAWoVChMIw9mooNOJyQIVRaZyCh2Njgsx)). Retrieving all data in a single query will make your code more complex, which is why you should only do it if there is a significant and measurable benefit.

With that said, the single query version is likely to be *much faster* than executing multiple queries with different identifiers. This is because each `Statement` execution over JDBC includes some overhead caused by e.g. statement parsing by the DB, result set processing by the JDBC driver and I/O latencies. This phenomenon is also known by the mnemonic "row-by-row, [slow-by-slow](http://tkyte.blogspot.fi/2006/10/slow-by-slow.html)".

Answer (score 1):

> So, to recap one single big query that return a big object or more
>   than one call but that returns one small object?

Answer depends on your app requirement. Lets consider a scenario
Say you have  multiple dog breeds and their id stored in db.  Now if across the application different thread  are inquiring about dog breeds by their ID very frequently then its good to bring data in single query and store it in cache. If someone asks for, you return it from cache. It improves the time performance but has memory overhead. Memory overhead can be ignored if you have infrastructure to support . If data is constant(it does not change like once server is started) in db , then you can keep cache strategy as `read` but if it can change with time, then you should keep it `read-write` so that fresh data is brought once it has been modified in db

On the other hand, users are not inquiring very frequently, then its good to bring the record just in time as it will save us memory overhead